# php array construct and display

Tags: php, arrays

How should I construct and retrieve php array to be able to display it like that.

April

```
Item | month, year, day 
Item | month, year, day 
Item | month, year, day 
Item | month, year, day
```

May

```
Item | month, year, day 
Item | month, year, day 
Item | month, year, day 
Item | month, year, day
```

ant etc.

Comment: Need a bit of context... Or is it homework?

Comment: @boisvert thanks, why do people always downvote instead of asking for clarification?

Comment: Reading this may help you http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what your dataset looks like prior to adding it to an array.  Without knowing that I would say you could do something very simple like this

```
$arr = array('Item 1' => '10, 2012, 5', 'Item 2' => '11, 2012, 6');

foreach ($arr as $akey => $aval) {
    echo $akey . " | " . $aval . "<br/>";
}
```

outputs:

Item 1 | 10, 2012, 5

Item 2 | 11, 2012, 6

At popular request here is a multidimesional example

```
$arr = array('May' => array('Item 1' => '5, 2012, 5', 'Item 2' => '5, 2012, 6'), 'June' => array('Item 1' => '6, 2012, 5', 'Item 2' => '6, 2012, 6'), 'July' => array('Item 1' => '7, 2012, 5', 'Item 2' => '7, 2012, 6'));

foreach ($arr as $akey => $aval) {
    echo $akey . "<br/>";
    foreach ($aval as $mkey => $mval) {
        echo $mkey . " | " . $mval . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

output:

May

Item 1 | 5, 2012, 5

Item 2 | 5, 2012, 6

June

Item 1 | 6, 2012, 5

Item 2 | 6, 2012, 6

July

Item 1 | 7, 2012, 5

Item 2 | 7, 2012, 6

Comment: That's pretty much the simplest; if you want this classified by Month, then you probably want a multi-dimensional array, to have the month separate from the rest, or several separate arrays. Tell us more!!!

Comment: @boisvert Added a multidimensional array in there for you :)